# Bind Service and listen for variable changes in the service in main activity

Tags: android, variables, service, binding, listener

I am trying to test out a simple service using Android's accelerometer but I'm not sure where to go from here.  What I want it to do is to detect movement using the service and for the main activity to detect every time there is a change in the boolean variable 'moving' that is in the service.

Not shown here is my manifest in which I already put in the code for the service.

Here is my main activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private boolean mBound = false;
    private accelService mService = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, accelService.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                       IBinder service) {

            accelService.LocalBinder binder = (accelService.LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            showMessage("Service Bound");
            mBound = true;

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };
    private void showMessage(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

Here is my Service.

```
public class accelService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {
    private boolean moving = false;
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    private SensorManager sensorManager;


    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        sensorManager.registerListener(this,
                sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        setMoving(true);
    }

    public boolean isMoving() {
        return moving;

    }

    public void setMoving(boolean moving) {
        this.moving = moving;
    }

    class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        accelService getService() {
            return accelService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have a "getService()" that the MainActivity can call, right? Ok.
You have to create a new Interface in the Service class that acts as a Callback:

```
class accelService extends Service {
    interface myCallback {
        void onCalled(int parameter);
    }
}
```

Then in your "LocalBinder" you add a new method and a variable:

```
class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    private myCallback mListener = null;

    accelService getService() {....} //<!-- the one you already have

    void addListener(myCallback listener) {  //<!-- the new one that sets the listener/callback
        myCallback = listener;
    }
}
```

At this point from your MainActivity you can call:

```
binder.addListener(new myCallback(){
    Toast.makeText(context, "Test", Toast.LONG).show()
});
```

as you do with "getService()".

Finally you have to call

```
mBinder.onCalled(123456789)
```

somewhere in the Service to execute Toast...show() procedure.
In this way you can pass variables from Service to MainActivity while this last one is bounded to the Service.